# .Net Core service using value from another service

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm currently trying to find a better way to call a function of a service in the constructor of another class service.  I have a bad feeling about what I'm doing and think I'm fighting the foundation of ASP .Net Core.  My question is, am I fighting the .Net way? Is there a better way where I'm not creating a new instance of CryptionService?

```
//this singleton has a function called GetSQLitePassword that returns a string
services.AddSingleton<ICryptionService, CryptionService>();

// Use value returned from cryptionService
services.AddScoped<ISQLiteSettingsRepo, 
    SQLiteSettingsRepo>(x => new SQLiteSettingsRepo(
        "./Settings.db", 
        new CryptionService().GetSQLitePassword()
    ));
```

I'd like to think that I could do something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ISQLiteSettingsRepo, SQLiteSettingsRepo>(x => new SQLiteSettingsRepo(
    "./Settings.db", 
    service.GetService<ICryptionService>().GetSQLitePassword()
 ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the part: `x => new SQLiteSettingsRepo(...`?
You should inject the `ICryptionService` service on the constructor of `SQLiteSettingsRepo`